# Append Dupplicates First Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, append

I am facing 2 issues if someone can help me that would be great.

1. Append duplicates .blog-post first time when I try to click load more button but it works fine on second click.
2. On fast clicking or double click it duplicates same post again and again.

```js
// AJAX Load More Blog Posts
    function AJAXLoadMorePosts(){
        $('.load-more-posts').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            // Variables
            var element = $(this);
            var target = element.attr('href');
            var post_wrapper = $('.blog-posts-wrapper');                

            // Run AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: target,
                success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {                   

                    // Store New Data
                    var new_post_items = $(data).find('.blog-posts-wrapper .blog-post');
                    var next_page_url = $(data).find('.nav-previous a').attr('href');

                    // Update Load More Button Href
                    if (next_page_url) {
                        element.attr('href', next_page_url);
                    } else {
                        element.slideUp();
                    }


                        post_wrapper.append(new_post_items);


                },
                complete: function() {
                    element.html(loadingTextOrg);
                },
                error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, `AJAXLoadMorePosts()` attaches the `$('.load-more-posts')` click handler, with two consequences :

1. No click handler is attached until `AJAXLoadMorePosts()` has been called for the first time.
2. On subsequent calls `AJAXLoadMorePosts()` will attach more and more click handlers, which is thoroughly undesirable.

The solution is to attach the click handler to all the relevant elements *once* (or delegate to a wrapping element).

You also need to ensure that the click handler performs a test such that it will only undertake the ajax if an ajax request is not already in progress.

Something like this should do it.

```
// AJAX Load More Blog Posts
$('.load-more-posts').text(loadingTextOrg).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $element = $(this);
    if($element.text() == loadingTextOrg) {
        var $element = $(this).text(somethngElse);
        $.get($element.attr('href')).then(function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            var next_page_url = $(data).find('.nav-previous a').attr('href');
            if (next_page_url) {
                $element.attr('href', next_page_url);
            } else {
                $element.slideUp();
            }
            $('.blog-posts-wrapper').append($(data).find('.blog-posts-wrapper .blog-post'));
        }, function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }).always(function() {
            $element.text(loadingTextOrg);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right about point 1. I changed var $element = $(this); to var element = $('.nav-previous a'); and its working fine. Now problem is how should I check if its last post its duplicating last post again and again because $element  is always showing last post url

Comment: Maybe I missed the point about duplicates. Do you mean that the server will return the same post(s) over and over again?